# Webpage loading lags a lot due to massive amount of records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, pagination

**HTML:**

```
<div id="table-wrapper"> 
    <div id="table-scroll">
    <div id="loading"></div>
    <table id="results" class="hidden" cellspacing=10px>
        <thead>
            <tr class = "spacing">
                <th class='headers'>Index No</th>
                <th class='headers'>SAM ID</th>
                <th class='headers'>Item Description</th>
                <th class='headers'>Type</th>
                <th class='headers'>Inventory Status</th>
                <th class='headers'>Issued QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Opening QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Closing QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Corrupted QTY</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date In</th>
                <th class='headers'>Date Out</th>
                <th class='headers'>Remarks</th>
                <th class='headers'>NTA SAM Reference No.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bResults"></tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   $("#loading").show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $("#loading").hide();
});

$(".navbar-search").one('click', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/queryAllRecord", // server url
    type: "POST", //POST or GET
    contentType: "application/json",
     // data to send in ajax format or querystring format
    dataType : "JSON", 
    success: function(response) {
         if(response){
            var len = response.length;
            var txt = "";
            if(len > 0){
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    if(response[i].samID){
                        txt += "<tr class='rowdata'>"+"<td 
                                 class='editNumber'></td>"
                                +"<td class='searchSam 
                                 editNumber'>"+response[i].samID+"</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].itemDescription +"</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].Type+"</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].InventoryStatus
                                +"</td>"+"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].issuedQTY + "</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].openingQTY + "</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>" 
                                +response[i].closingQTY+"</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].corruptedQTY+"</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].dateIn+"</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].dateOut+"</td>"
                                +"<td class='editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].Remarks+"</td>"
                                +"<td class='searchNta editNumber'>"
                                +response[i].ntaRequestRef+"</td>"
                                +"<td><button class='input button-edit' 
                                type='submit' id='edit' 
                                onclick = 'edit(this)'>Edit</button></td>" 
                                +"<td><input class='input button-delete' 
                                type='button' id='delete' value='Delete' 
                                onclick='deleteResult(this)' /></td>"+"
                                </tr>";
                    }
                }

                $("#bResults").empty();
                if(txt != ""){
                    $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
                    $("#bResults").append(txt);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('error');
    }
    });
event.preventDefault();
});
function test(pageNumber)
{
 var page="#page-id-"+pageNumber;
  $('.select').hide()
  $(page).show()
}
$(function() {
$('#nice').pagination({
    items: 14000,
    itemsOnPage: 100,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    onPageClick: function(pageNumber){test(pageNumber)}
});
});
```

Basically, my ajax will respond with a huge amount of records that will then be displayed in a table. The records are around 13000 and it will keep increasing so I need a way to make it load quicker and not have problems on lagging etc. I found pagination as a way to perhaps make it load quicker but unsure as to whether this is the right solution to this problem. I tried simple pagination.js plugin but unsure as to what pagination placeholder means.

**Is there any other ways to make the webpage not be laggy even when it is loading 14000 records and more in the future?**

**Is there any other plugin for pagination that has clearer examples on how to implement the plugin into the js code and html as I am rather new to pagination and don't understand how it works.**

I am running it on node.js and retrieving data from mongodb. I know it is my 13000++ records that is making the webpage load slowly but I need the 13000++ records to be shown in pages or in a whole as I am also doing live search on the html table as well so if anyone has any suggestions on allowing the webpage to perform better except minify, please feel free to suggest in the comments or answers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case I'd highly recommend [JQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/).

Datatables lets you do exactly what you're trying to do here, with the added advantage of implementing pagination and a handful of other useful utilities for you.

Specifically, the feature of Datatables that will help you solve this problem is the [Server Side Processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) option. Essentially, it lets you query a very large dataset (from wherever your data is stored), but only load manageable portions of it into the DOM at a time; again, handling the loading/unloading and pagination settings for you automatically.

A great tutorial explaining how to use this feature with a PHP backend script [can be found here](http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-dom-php-ajax-mysql-datasources/)

Answer (score 0):

pagination, you said it, try to load smaller amounts of data at a time.  You can't show 13000 records in the browser at a time anyway.  I usually load only the data I can display in the browser at a time.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are right about pagination. That seems the logical thing to do for reducing the loading time and keeping the page length short.
2. You can request data using limits and offsets as you scroll down the page and keep plotting new entries.
3. You can request the entries at once but you can plot a limited of them and as you scroll down you plot the next set. This way rendering of data will be easy and it won't put a lot of load on the page and on loading time.